# Why are these concurrent transactions causing a deadlock? (mysql 8.0 innoDB)

Tags: mysql, innodb

Let's say we have the following table

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS humans;
USE humans;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS address (
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (last_name)
);


INSERT INTO address values ("x", "abcd");
INSERT INTO address values ("y", "asdf");


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names (
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (first_name, last_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (last_name) REFERENCES address(last_name)
);
```

I am adding records to the names table, but before adding it, I am deleting all the records and then re-creating them (just to reproduce the deadlock)

Start 2 separate transactions. transaction-1

```
START transaction;
DELETE FROM names where last_name="x";
<do not commit or rollback>
```

transaction-2

```
START transaction
DELETE FROM names where last_name="y";
<do not commit or rollback>
```

And then in transaction-1

```
INSERT INTO names VALUES ("a", "x");
```

and in transaction-2

```
INSERT INTO names VALUES  ("b", "y");
```

This results in a deadlock.

I am not sure why though. IIUC, innoDB locks rows of the table, and not the entire table. Both the transactions are deleting separate records and adding separate records. So why is there a deadlock?

Here are more details

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.33    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table names;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| names | CREATE TABLE `names` (
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`first_name`,`last_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the deadlock from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-06-13 09:46:39 0x700005d8d000
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 23728, ACTIVE 305 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1177, OS thread handle 123145414819840, query id 307296 localhost root update
INSERT INTO names VALUES ("a", "x")

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 492 page no 5 n bits 72 index last_name of table `humans`.`names` trx id 23728 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 492 page no 5 n bits 72 index last_name of table `humans`.`names` trx id 23728 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 23729, ACTIVE 302 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1178, OS thread handle 123145415884800, query id 307297 localhost root update
INSERT INTO names VALUES  ("b", "y")

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 492 page no 5 n bits 72 index last_name of table `humans`.`names` trx id 23729 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 492 page no 5 n bits 72 index last_name of table `humans`.`names` trx id 23729 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
```

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `select version();` and `show create table names;` (which will differ from your CREATE TABLE)

Comment: does the deadlock happen without the foreign key too?

Comment: mysql let to  it iwn devices with auto commit can resolve most lock problems, when yoiu try to hadlw it on your own, you get this, why is the transaction not committed, are you waiting hot, colse them as soon as possible or change your logic to avoid deadlocks

Comment: > does the deadlock happen without the foreign key too? 

Yes

Comment: > If you use a third session to check the contents of performance_schema.data_locks after each step in your example above, you should be able to see exactly what is happening.

Thanks. I do see the reason. The transactions are waiting on each other. But it does not tell me why. The lock_type is on the record (which means the lock is on a row?)

Comment: @user1191247 Thanks. I added the details from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`.  Could help me understand this? 

I see that both the transactions are holding locks on the index last_name. But is it the entire table, or just the last_name which has been requested to be deleted?

Comment: The IX-lock required for the insert to go ahead cannot be granted due to the pending delete in the other transaction, I think.

Comment: You could swap the order in the primary key of first/last name.

Answer (score 0):

Without an index on `last_name`, the `DELETEs` must search the entire table.  No, the PK that you have does not help.

Adding `INDEX(last_name)` may solve your problem.  More efficient would be (see @danblack), to change to `PRIMARY KEY(last_name, first_name)` unless there is some reason to need the locality of reference of `first_name`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the default [transaction isolation level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) ([`REPEATABLE READ`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read)) and your schema above with the FK on `last_name` which gives us an index on `last_name`. An important point to note is that `names` is empty at this point.

Start tx1:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM names WHERE last_name = 'x';
```

Start tx2:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM names WHERE last_name = 'y';
```

data_locks

| tx | object_schema | object_name | index_name | lock_type | lock_mode | lock_status | lock_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tx2 | humans | names |  | TABLE | IX | GRANTED |  |
| tx2 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X | GRANTED | supremum pseudo‑record |
| tx1 | humans | names |  | TABLE | IX | GRANTED |  |
| tx1 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X | GRANTED | supremum pseudo‑record |

We can see from the above the two [intension exclusive locks (IX)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-intention-locks) on the `names` table and, due to the table being empty, the only way we can get a lock on the `last_name` index is with a lock on the `supremum pseudo‑record`, locking the entire index and this is granted to both transactions.

Now when we try to the `INSERT` in `tx1`:

```sql
INSERT INTO names VALUES ('a', 'x');
```

We can see that `tx1` is `waiting` for a lock on the `last_name` index:

| tx | object_schema | object_name | index_name | lock_type | lock_mode | lock_status | lock_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tx2 | humans | names |  | TABLE | IX | GRANTED |  |
| tx2 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X | GRANTED | supremum pseudo‑record |
| tx1 | humans | address |  | TABLE | IS | GRANTED |  |
| tx1 | humans | names |  | TABLE | IX | GRANTED |  |
| tx1 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X | GRANTED | supremum pseudo‑record |
| tx1 | humans | address | PRIMARY | RECORD | S,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED | 'x' |
| tx1 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X,INSERT_INTENTION | WAITING | supremum pseudo‑record |

When we attempt the `INSERT` in `tx2` the deadlock is immediately detected and `tx2` is rolled back, releasing its locks, allowing `tx1` to continue, leaving us with the following locks:

| tx | object_schema | object_name | index_name | lock_type | lock_mode | lock_status | lock_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tx1 | humans | address |  | TABLE | IS | GRANTED |  |
| tx1 | humans | names |  | TABLE | IX | GRANTED |  |
| tx1 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X | GRANTED | supremum pseudo‑record |
| tx1 | humans | address | PRIMARY | RECORD | S,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED | 'x' |
| tx1 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X,INSERT_INTENTION | GRANTED | supremum pseudo‑record |
| tx1 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X,GAP | GRANTED | 'x', 'a' |

If we start again, but this time inserting `xx` record between `x` and `y`, before starting `tx1` and `tx2`:

```sql
INSERT INTO address (last_name, address) VALUES ('xx', 'abcdxx');
INSERT INTO names (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('a', 'xx');
```

After starting `tx1` and `tx2`, and running their respective `DELETE` statements, we have the following data_locks:

| tx | object_schema | object_name | index_name | lock_type | lock_mode | lock_status | lock_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tx2 | humans | names |  | TABLE | IX | GRANTED |  |
| tx2 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X | GRANTED | supremum pseudo‑record |
| tx1 | humans | names |  | TABLE | IX | GRANTED |  |
| tx1 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X,GAP | GRANTED | 'xx', 'a' |

Notice how the locks are now different after the `DELETE`s, with `tx1` having an exclusive (X) [gap lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks), which locks the gap before record `'xx'`. And, `tx2` still has a [next-key lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-next-key-locks) on the supremum pseudo-record and the gap before it. But this now represents all records in the index after `xx`, instead of the whole of the empty index before.

The `INSERT`s will now succeed in both of the transactions:

| tx | object_schema | object_name | index_name | lock_type | lock_mode | lock_status | lock_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tx2 | humans | address |  | TABLE | IS | GRANTED |  |
| tx2 | humans | names |  | TABLE | IX | GRANTED |  |
| tx2 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X | GRANTED | supremum pseudo‑record |
| tx2 | humans | address | PRIMARY | RECORD | S,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED | 'y' |
| tx2 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X,GAP | GRANTED | 'y', 'b' |
| tx1 | humans | address |  | TABLE | IS | GRANTED |  |
| tx1 | humans | names |  | TABLE | IX | GRANTED |  |
| tx1 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X,GAP | GRANTED | 'x', 'a' |
| tx1 | humans | names | last_name | RECORD | X,GAP | GRANTED | 'xx', 'a' |
| tx1 | humans | address | PRIMARY | RECORD | S,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED | 'x' |

Answer (score -1):

Because both transactions are waiting for a resource to become available, neither ever release the locks it holds.

```
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT value FROM Birds WHERE name='Buzzard' FOR SHARE;
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|    20 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```